# Composition of two Mobius maps on the unit disc in $\Bbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a,b \in \Bbb D$, the unit disc in the complex plane, and let $\varphi_{a}(z)$ and $\varphi_{b}(z)$ be two typical Mobius maps on $\Bbb D$. Is there a well known formula for the composition of these two maps? Is it another Mobius map?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ two-by-two matrices? If so, the composition is $\varphi_{ab}$. No matter what, they compose to a Möbius map.

Comment: They are points in the disc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming OP is referring to the unit disk automorphisms (special case of Möbius transformations):

$\varphi$ is a unit disk Automorphism, meaning $\varphi_a(z) = \lambda\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$ with $|\lambda|=1 $.

The composition of two unit disk automorphisms remains a unit disk automorphism. You can calculate it exactly by using the matrix representation of Möbius maps, and the property that $T_A\circ T_B = T_{AB}$ for $T$ Mobius and $A,B$ matrices.

Another way to look at it is that $\varphi_a(z)=0$ iff $z=a$. Therefore, 
$\varphi_a(z) \circ \varphi_b(z)$ = $\varphi_a(\varphi_b(z))=0$ iff $\varphi_b(z)=a$. Now taking $\varphi_b^{-1}$ on both sides [which is equal $\varphi_{-b}$] we get $a=\varphi_{-b}(z)$.

So $\varphi_a(z) \circ \varphi_b(z) = \varphi_{\varphi_{-b}(a)}(z)$.